# Where is the data from datatables dataset stored?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

Let's say we have this URL:

http://www-odi.nhtsa.dot.gov/owners/SearchResults?prodType=V&searchType=PROD&targetCategory=A&searchCriteria.model=&stats=&makeStats=&jsonBaseURL=%2Fdownloads%2Ffolders%2F&searchCriteria.model_yr=2013&searchCriteria.make=ALTEC&searchCriteria.prod_ids=-1

Regarding to my firebug there is no network activity when I browse through the dataset (for e.g. "next") or change the displayed items.

This means to me that the data must be loaded from the beginning. 
My research in the sourcecode of the website did not succeed.

Can anybody tell me where all the data from the dataset is stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [**documentation**](https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/):

> DataTables can obtain data from four different fundamental sources:
>
> - HTML document (DOM)
> - Javascript (array / objects)
> - Ajax sourced data with client-side processing
> - Ajax sourced data with server-side processing
>
> Which of these options is used to populate the table with data depends upon how the table is initialised.

On that particular page they are using a Javascript source from variables and data which are in fact loaded along with the html.

They first construct an array called `statsArray`.  Then iterate over this array, declaring variables in the loop and finally use the function `fnAddData()` to load the data into the table (line 177):

```
$('#table_id').dataTable().fnAddData( [
    [desc,recl, inv, comp, tsbs]
]);
```